# How to change Entity Model in MVC without rebuilding the Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model that include some table and I've made her database.Now,I want to change some fields Without wanting to make a new controller.

My Users Model :

```
public partial class Users
{

    public Users()
    { this.NEWSs = new HashSet<NEWS>(); }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public int UserGroupID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NEWS> NEWSs { get; set; }

}
```

For example i want to change Password property to [required] No need to re-build controller

Comment: Why would you have to build a new controller? I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you don´t need to create a new controller.

If you´ve enabled migrations, you have to add a migration or rescaffold the last one.